# Issue with # character in SQL search string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I use some Regexp in my mySQL search queries and it seems to work fine unless I have a # character in the query.

The Regexp matches based on word boundaries because the field in which this query is searching is entire resumes / curriculum-vitaes stored in the SQL database.

For instance this works as expected and returns the correct number of results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[[:<:]]java[[:>:]]');
```

However, this doesn't and returns 0 results when it should return a few hundred:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[[:<:]]c#[[:>:]]');
```

I understand now that this is because I am matching based on word boundaries and # cannot be the end of the word. Interestingly, "C++" works fine though.

Is there a way of modifying this REGEXP so it also works with a string like "c#"?

Comment: have you tried escaping the `#` like `\#`. not sure if this is a protected syntax char but you can give it a try

Comment: The following doesn't work unfortunately SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.Skillset REGEXP '[[:<:]]c\#[[:>:]]');

Comment: mhh here is a online debugger for SQL regex [click_me](https://www.regextester.com/99656)

Comment: That would be true for any non-word character, your matching on boundaries and there is a boundary between C and #

Comment: I terms of *regular expressions* `#` is not a word character. `#[[:>:]]` will never match anything, because `#` can not be *end of word*. In this special case I'd suggest to normalize your schema and use a many-to-many relation `candidate_skill`.

Comment: Giving that `c#` is not a common word that you'll find in a CV other than near the skills set, why not make it as an exception and select it with a `like '%c#%'` or `regexp 'c#'`?

Comment: Please precise the version of MySQL you are using. The latest 8 version uses ICU regex engine that is quite different from the previous POSIX one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT 'c#' REGEXP '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])c#($|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])'
SELECT 'java' REGEXP '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])java($|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])'
```

In newer MySQL versions (8.0.4+) which support regex through ICU instead of Henry Spencer's implementation you can use `\w` which looks a bit cleaner:

```
SELECT 'c#' REGEXP '(^|[^\w])c#($|[^\w])'
SELECT 'java' REGEXP '(^|[^\w])java($|[^\w])'
```

Comment: Most versions of MySQL do no handle `\w`.

Comment: for older MySQL versions: `SELECT 'c#' REGEXP '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])c#($|[^a-zA-Z0-9])'`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I think this is the best answer, but I would suggest you incorporate your comment (replacing [^\w] with [^a-zA-Z0-9]) into your answer.  Comments can disappear, answers, less so.  Also, \w includes an underbar, which the OP may or may not consider a word character for these purposes, so I think spelling it out is better even if \w is available.

Comment: You are right! I edited the answer. I added an underscore to the pattern as well, which is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks! This was the kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

One option could be substitution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n 
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(cv, '#','sharp') AS cv FROM candidate) c 
WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[[:<:]]csharp[[:>:]]');
```

Comment: just be aware that this matches `csharp` as well as `c#`, which might be a desirable side effect

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve more or less what you want using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]java[^[:alpha:]]');
```

which can work for the C# case, like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]c#[^[:alpha:]]');
```

Note that if you just replace c# with c++ you will run into problems, because this regex is invalid:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]c++[^[:alpha:]]');
```

whereas

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]c\\+\\+[^[:alpha:]]');
```

works for me (using the mysql CLI)

If you are fussy about these words appearing as the start/end of the text, you can use something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM candidate c WHERE (c.CV REGEXP '[^[:alpha:]]c#[^[:alpha:]]|^c#|c#$');
```

This is pretty close to the word-boundary requirement.

Comment: Suggest `alnum` instead of `alpha`.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why can't you use something like this

`[[:<:]]c#([^#a-zA-Z0-9_]|$)`

since `[[:>:]]` is an end of word boundary meaning a *word behind* AND *not a word ahead*,
but # is not a word and you still need not a word ahead and I assume not a # ahead.

Answer (score 0):

`#` can be used as a regex delimiter. Thus you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
'[[:<:]]c\#[[:>:]]'
```